# Deleting An item from a List Box from a Database

Tags: c#

Hi Im trying to delete an item from the listbox which the user selects here you can find my code and a screenshot tnx.

Code:

```
public void deleteEvent(ListBox list_event)
{
    int i = list_event.SelectedIndex;

    ds.Tables["tblEvents"].Rows[i].Delete();
    da.Update(ds.Tables["tblEvents"]);
}
```

Im getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object Exception.

ScreenShot: 
[image]

Comment: How do you populate the listbox?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `ds` is not null.
- Make sure there is a table called `tblEvents` in the data set, `ds`.
- Make sure the number of rows in the `tblEvents` is large enough so that the index you're using when deleting fits within the number of rows.
- Make sure that the data adapter `da` is not null.

Without any further information, it's close to impossible to give any more insights.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key?