# Deleting An item from a List Box from a Database

Tags: c#

I'm getting this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Missing the DataColumn 'Member_ID' in the DataTable 'tblEvents' for the SourceColumn 'Member_ID'.
```

which certainly makes no sense, as I'm working with another table here you can find my code and a screenshot thanks.

```
public void deleteEvent(ListBox list_event)
{
     int i = list_event.SelectedIndex;

     ds.Tables["tblEvents"].Rows[i].Delete();
     da.Update(ds.Tables["tblEvents"]);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773539/deleting-an-item-from-a-list-box-from-a-database

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, but is it possible that DataTable does not contain a column named 'Member_ID' ?